# Почему то не запускается сервер. Выясняю почему

Tags: веб-программирование, django, python-3.x

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Начал изучать Django. Создал проект и пытаюсь запустить сервер. Ничего не получается.

После комментария о том, что родительский каталог содержит кириллические символы, я внес правки, но сервер все равно не запускается.

Фактически, выводит то же самое. Несмотря на то, что теперь родительский каталог не содержит кириллические символы.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Объясните пожалуйста, что тут не так.

После выполнения hostname выводит вот это - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проблема в том, что родительский каталог содержит кириллические символы. Создайте на диске C: каталог Projects, а проекты создавайте в нём.

Comment: Что выводит выполнение команды `hostname`?

Comment: В имени хоста тоже не должно быть кириллических символов.